# Firefox autostart kiosk or fullscreen on start-up

Tags: firefox, autostart, fullscreen, kiosk

I have Linux installed and I am trying to autostart Firefox full screen or in kiosk mode every time I start my PC. I kind of know there is a command like `xdotool.....windowactivate key F11`, but that only works once.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to my knowledge Firefox (still?) lacks kiosk mode.

As for xdotool, what do you mean with "only works once"?

If you have a script that starts Firefox, just add xdotool after it. Example (for Chromium):

```
    #!/bin/bash
    chromium https://www.bing.com --window-size=1920,1080 --start-fullscreen --kiosk --incognito --noerrdialogs --disable-translate --no-first-run --fast --fast-start --disable-infobars --disable-features=TranslateUI --disk-cache-dir=/dev/null  --password-store=basic &
    xdotool key F11
```

Just make sure to add "&" behind a command starting your browser and then xdtool will work

While it's not the question, I can still suggest Chromium as an alternative, see script above, it can nicely start in fullscreen, in kiosk mode, with many features disabled, optionally with --incognito as well.